How to get link status and speed of a NIC which is installed rtnet driver
I am using rt_igb for my NIC and I would like to get the link status and speed using C programming languages. I tried to use ETHTOOL as suggested in Get link speed programmatically?. However, "Operation not supported" was returned. Can anyone help me to solve my problem? Thank you.
My test code:
#include <linux/ethtool.h>
#include <linux/if.h>
#include <linux/sockios.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct ethtool_cmd edata = {.cmd = ETHTOOL_GSET};
    struct ifreq ifr = {.ifr_name = "rteth0", .ifr_data = &edata};

    int sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (ioctl(sock, SIOCETHTOOL, &ifr) < 0) {
        perror("ioctl");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    switch (ethtool_cmd_speed(&edata)) {
        case SPEED_10: printf("10Mbps\n"); break;
        case SPEED_100: printf("100Mbps\n"); break;
        case SPEED_1000: printf("1Gbps\n"); break;
        case SPEED_2500: printf("2.5Gbps\n"); break;
        case SPEED_10000: printf("10Gbps\n"); break;
        default: printf("Speed returned is %d\n", edata.speed);
    }
}

Output: "Operation not supported"
When I disconnect/connect LAN cable from the Ethernet port, the following kernel logs are displayed:
Apr 10 13:38:32 laptop kernel: [16948.074380] rt_igb: rteth0: igb: rteth0 NIC Link is Down
Apr 10 13:41:26 laptop kernel: [17122.113260] rt_igb: rteth0: igb: rteth0 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX


Simpler is to read the file /sys/class/net/<interface>/speed

For real-time ethernet driver, the interface is not located in /sys/class/net.
It is located in the /sys/class/rtnet/ but there is no "speed" file
